# Heroku app throwing Error: self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm using free tier of heroku to deploy an app. I've managed to create the app with the build being successful on heroku. I pushed to heroku and tried `heroku local` and the app runs as it should. However if I try `heroku open` the browser opens to the heroku "Application error" page.

I tried running `NODE_ENV=production heroku local` as a troubleshooting step and that does cause the app to break. I get

```
Error: self signed certificate
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1492:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (evens.js:315:20)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:935:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:693:12)
```

The github repo is here: https://github.com/JoeCastr/budget_app

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "budget_app_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "budget.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx nodemon budget.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "connect-loki": "^1.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.5.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.12.0",
    "npm": "6.14.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with pg version 8.x it breaks heroku. the connection constant needs to be:

```
const CONNECTION = { 
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL, 
    ssl: { 
        rejectUnauthorized: false 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After so much struggle this works for me:

```
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.yourDatabaseURL,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
  
})
```